# OpenBugs: Poor mixing and prior specification

Tags: indexing, nested, bayesian, winbugs

I'm hoping someone can help fit a nonlinear model in OpenBUGS. The problem is somewhat ill posed but we have lots of data.

We have a network of traps that collect leaf litter in a forest plot of mapped trees.

I'm trying to determine the allometric relationship between tree diameter and litter production by fitting the following model:

The expected amount of litter collected at a location that is "z" meters away from a tree of diameter "DBH" cm

```
tree1.litter = alpha*gamma^2 * DBH^Beta/(2*pi)  *   exp(-gamma*z-delta*DBH)
```

However, our trap data contains input from multiple trees.

```
Obs.Litter = tree1.litter + tree2.litter + ... + treej.litter + error
```

The data are formatted as follows:

```
list(Total.trees = 646, N.trap=4.600E+01, 
DBH=c(3.470E+01, 2.940E+01,...)  diameters (cm) for 656 trees
z=c(2.500E+01, 1.632E+01, ...)   displacment (m) for 656 trees
trap.id = c(1, 1, 1,1, 1,  2, 2,, 2, 2, ..., 46, 46) for 656 trees
Obs.Litter = c(24, 12, ...)  amount of litter(g) for each of 46 traps
cumulative.trees = c(36, 39, ...)      cumulative number of trees in each of 46 trap neighborhoods


model{

for(i in 1:Total.trees){    
    tree[i] <- alpha*pow(gamma,2)/(2*3.141593) * pow(DBH[i],Beta) *exp(-gamma*z[i]-delta*DBH[i])
}

Obs.Litter[1] ~ dnorm(Expected.Litter[1], tau)
Expected.Litter[1]<- sum(tree[1 : cumulative.trees[1]])

for(j in 2: N.trap){
    Obs.Litter[j] ~ dnorm(Expected.Litter[j], tau)
    Expected.Litter[j] <- sum(tree[cumulative.trees[j-1]: cumulative.trees[j]  ])
}

#Priors
tau ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
sigma <- 1/sqrt(tau)
alpha~dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
Beta~dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
gamma~dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
delta~dgamma(0.001, 0.001)

}


list(alpha=20,Beta=5,gamma=5,delta=5,tau = 10)
list(alpha=20,Beta=6,gamma=2,delta=1,tau = 10)
```

I have made progress on this and have update the post a couple times. I've been able to run a Gibb's sampler, but am not getting satisfactory mixing, and unreasonable results. Observed Litter values are in the 10s of grams, but I'm estimating <10^-7 g litter input.

Since I expect all the parameters take on positive values, I decided to go with gamma priors. I think the issue lies in the priors. My intent is to use ignorant priors, but I have a vague idea that the parameters will take on the following values:
    alpha = 2 : 20
    Beta = ~2
    gamma = .2
    delta = .02